# Converter array Bidimensional em String Separado por virgula

Tags: php, lógica

Preciso converter esse Array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [value] => pdf
        [label] => PDF
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [value] => csv
        [label] => CSV
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [value] => rtf
        [label] => RTF
    )
)
```

Em uma String trazendo apenas o label separado por vírgula. Ex:

```
PDF, CSV, RTF
```

Utilizei dois `foreachs` concatenando em uma variável e espaço e virgula, e um `substr` para remover a primeira virgula.

Ex:

```
foreach ($formatos as $row[label]){
    foreach ($row as $formato => $a){
        $b .= ', '.$a[label];
    }
}
echo $arq = substr($b, 1);
```

Deve ter um jeito mais fácil de fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certamente há uma maneira mais fácil de concatenar esse valores em uma string:

- Com [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-column.php) obtenha um array contendo os valores de `label`.
- Com [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php) junte elementos em uma string.

```php
<?php

$formatos = [
  [
    'value' => 'pdf',
    'label' => 'PDF'
  ],
  [
    'value' => 'csv',
    'label' => 'CSV'
  ],
  [
    'value' => 'rtf',
    'label' => 'RTF'
  ]
];

$arq = implode(", ", array_column($formatos, 'label'));
echo $arq;  //PDF, CSV, RTF
```

<sup>Teste no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/arq#main.php)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pelo auxílio [Augusto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/137387/augusto-vasques)

A sua resposta foi exelente.

Precisei incluir o `array_combine()`

```
    $formato = array_combine(array_keys($formatos), array_column($formatos, 'label'));
    $arq = implode(", ",$formato);
```

Diminuindo de 6 linhas para apenas duas e sem precisar da Gambi da virgula `substr($b, 1);`  ;-)